# Understanding two facts about simple left modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

On one hand, we have

> Proposition 1. If $M$ is a left ideal of a ring $R$, satisfying $RM\neq 0$, then $M$ is a simple left $R$-module *iff* $M$ is a *minimal* left ideal.

On the other hand, we also have

> Proposition 2. A left $R$-module $M$ is simple *iff* there is a $R$-module isomorphism from $M$ to $R/I$, where $I$ is a *modular* maximal left ideal.

**Question:** Does the above mean, if $M$ is a minimal left ideal of $R$, then there exists a maximal modular left ideal $N$ of $R$ such that $R=M\oplus N$? But if this is the case, since $N$ is modular, if $R$ has an identity, wouldn't it mean $M$ is supposed to contain the identity element, and so making it the whole ring? Thanks.

**Update:**

Based on the answer by @rschwieb, the correct statement should be

> For a *minimal* left ideal $M$ of a ring $R$ such that $RM\neq 0$, let $N$ be the kernel of $R$-module epimorphism $r\mapsto rm$ from $R$ to $M$, for a fixed $m\in M\setminus \{0\}$. Then, there is a $R$-module decomposition $R=M\oplus N$ *iff* $N\cap M=(0)$.

*Proof.* By the two propositions, we have exact sequence of $R$-modules $0\to N\to R\to M\to 0$. The inclusion map $\iota: M\hookrightarrow R$ is a section *iff* $N\cap M=(0)$. Then, by splitting lemma, we have $R= M\oplus N$ as left $R$-modules. $\square$

In this case, if $R$ has an identity, then there exists $m_e\in M$ such that $m_e\in 1_R +N$ or equivalently $m_e-1_R\in N$. This causes no contradictions to the module isomorphism $M\simeq R/N\ni [1_R]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the above mean, if $$ is a minimal left ideal of $$, then there exists a maximal modular left ideal $$ of $$ such that $=⊕$?

No, it does not mean that. Consider $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$. The ideal $M=2\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ is the unique maximal ideal and $R/M$ is a simple module, in fact, the only simple module for $R$ up to isomorphism.  There do not exist any pair $A,B$ of nonzero submodules such that $A\oplus B=R$.

> But if this is the case, since  is modular, if  has an identity, wouldn't it mean  is supposed to contain the identity element

No, there is no reason to say that. The definition of a modular right ideal $T$ is that there is an element $r\in R$ such that $rm-m\in T$ for every $m\in T$.  When $R$ has identity, then $r=1$ always works (that's why modularity is automatic in rings with identity.)  This does not imply at all that "$r\in T$".

Comment: If $R/M$ is a simple $R$-module, it's not necessarily a left ideal of $R$, but if it is, it seems we have a split exact sequence $0\to M\to R \to R/M$, and that seems to imply $R=M\oplus R/M$. Wrong?

For your example, $R=\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $M=\{0, 2\}$. So $R/M=\{0,1\}$. Don't we exactly have $\{0,1,2,3\}=\{0,2\}\oplus \{0,1\}$??

About the other one, if $R$ has identity, and $N$ is a maximal ideal, then there exists $m_e\in M$ such that $[m_e]=[1_R]$ but $1_R\notin M$. I didn't get this part when I posted the question.

Comment: Sorry, you are right that, for your example, we don't have $R=M\oplus R/M$. But that's because in your example $R/M$ is not an ideal of $R$. So it doesn't fall under the situation of my question.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.

Comment: @user760 In the example I gave, $M$ is _also_ a simple module, and is isomorphic to $R/M$ even.  $R$ is not equal to $A\oplus B$ for any two ideals $A,B$ _at all_. So one cannot find any complement to $M$ at all, of any form.

Comment: @user760 In your first comment, you always have that exact sequence yes, but in this example it _cannot split_.  (Also, last comment should read _any two nonzero ideals at all_)

Comment: I think I got it. So the issue with this example is that $M$ is both a minimal and a maximal ideal, and $R$ only has this one unique *proper* ideal. So the "section", aka $\iota\circ \alpha: R/M \to R$, where $\alpha$ is the isomorphism from $R/M$ to $M$, is not really a section, because the image of $\iota\circ \alpha$ is the kernel and so $\pi_M \circ \iota \circ \alpha=0$.